# How to implement a zoom funcitonality using QQuickPaintedItem in C++ on the mouse position on the Qimage painted by it?

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am trying to implemented a class from QQuickPaintedItem that paints a QImage and provides a functionality to zoom in based on the mouse position. I am overriding wheel event and paint but no luck so far.?
it zooms but not on the mouse pointer position.

Can somebody please help me implementing zoom in functionality? I also want to implement a functionality where on a button click it zooms out completely.

Below is the header implementation where i am overriding wheelevent.

```
#pragma once
#include <QtQuick>
#include <limits>

class ImageCanvas : public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QImage image READ image WRITE setImage NOTIFY imageChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(qreal zoom READ zoom WRITE setZoom NOTIFY zoomChanged)

  public:
    ImageCanvas(QQuickItem* parent = nullptr)
        : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
        , m_zoom(1.0),mOffset(QPointF(0, 0)), m_mousePos(0, 0), m_scale(1.0)
    {
        setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::AllButtons);
        setAcceptHoverEvents(true);
    }

    QImage image() const
    {
        return m_image;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE void setImage(const QImage& image)
    {
        m_image = image;
        update();
    }

    qreal zoom() const
    {
        return m_zoom;
    }
    Q_INVOKABLE void setZoom(qreal zoom)
    {
        if (zoom != m_zoom)
        {
            m_zoom = zoom;
            emit zoomChanged();
            update();
        }
    }
    
    void wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event) override
    {
        //QPointF mousePos = event->position();
        //qreal delta = event->angleDelta().y();
        //zoomAt(mousePos, delta);

        QPoint delta = event->angleDelta() / 120;
        qreal zoomDelta = delta.y() > 0 ? 1.1 : 0.9; // Increase or decrease zoom level by 10%
        qreal oldZoomLevel = m_zoom;
        m_zoom *= zoomDelta;
        if (m_zoom < 0.1)
        {
            // Limit zoom out to 10%
            m_zoom = 0.1;            
        }
        else if (m_zoom > 10.0)
        {
            // Limit zoom in to 1000%
            m_zoom = 10.0;
        }
        if (m_zoom != oldZoomLevel)
        {
            // Zoom around the mouse pointer
            QPointF pos = event->position();
            QPointF zoomedMousePos = (pos / oldZoomLevel - pos / m_zoom) / m_zoom;
            setTransformOriginPoint(pos);
            update();
        }

     
    }
    void zoomAt(const QPointF& mousePos, qreal delta)
    {
        qreal zoomFactor = qPow(1.2, delta / 240.0);
        m_zoom *= zoomFactor;
        m_mousePos = mousePos;

        update();
    }

  signals:
    void imageChanged();
    void zoomChanged();

  protected:
    void paint(QPainter* painter) override;


  private:
    QImage m_image;
    qreal m_zoom;
    QPointF mOffset;
    QPointF m_mousePos;
    qreal m_scale;
};

//C++ file implementing paint event

  void ImageCanvas::paint(QPainter* painter) 
{  

    painter->scale(m_zoom, m_zoom);
    painter->drawImage(QPointF(0, 0), m_image);
    //painter->restore();
}
```

The ImageCanvas is used in QML file like this:

```
Rectangle {
    id : rect
    color: "darkgrey"
    clip:true
  
    width: 500
    height: 500
                        

    App.ImageCanvas {
        id: imageItem
           focus: true
        anchors.centerIn: parent    
        
       }               

}
```

Where i set a QImage using the imageItem.setImage function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue by implementing the PinchArea and mouse wheel event on the QML side instead of doing that in C++. I originally got inspired by the "PhotoSource" example and then some inspiration taken from here: http://hybridcoding.blogspot.com/ which helped me in implementing a zoom in functionality at the mouse position on the custom QQuickPaintedItems.

I am sure the same cane be applied on "Image" type in QML.

```
    Rectangle {
        id : rect
        color: "blue"
        clip:true
        
        width: 600
        height: 6000

        Item {
            id: photoFrame
            width: rect.width
            height: rect.height
            clip: true                

            transform: Scale {
                id: scaler
                origin.x: pinchArea.x2
                origin.y: pinchArea.y2
                xScale: pinchArea.scale2
                yScale: pinchArea.scale2
            }
    
            // This could be an "Image" type as well
            CustomImageItem {
                id: imageItem
                focus: true
                anchors.fill: parent                    
            }
    
            PinchArea {
                id: pinchArea
                anchors.fill: parent
                property real x1: 0
                property real y1: 0
                property real y2: 0
                property real x2: 0
                property real scale1: 1
                property real scale2: 1
                property real maximumScale: 5
                property real minimumScale: 1                    
        
                onPinchUpdated: {                        
                    scale1 = scaler.xScale
                    var dz = pinch.scale-pinch.previousScale
                    var newZoom = scale1+dz
                    if (newZoom <= maximumScale && newZoom >= minimumScale) {
                        scale2 = newZoom
                    }
                }
                MouseArea {
                    id: dragArea
                    hoverEnabled: true
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    drag.target: photoFrame                        
                    scrollGestureEnabled: false 
                    onWheel: {                           
                        pinchArea.x1 = scaler.origin.x
                        pinchArea.y1 = scaler.origin.y
                        pinchArea.scale1 = scaler.xScale

                        //updating the pinch area x2 and y2 with current mouse position
                        pinchArea.x2 = mouseX
                        pinchArea.y2 = mouseY
                
                        var newZoom
                        if (wheel.angleDelta.y > 0) {
                            newZoom = pinchArea.scale1+0.1
                            if (newZoom <= pinchArea.maximumScale) {
                                pinchArea.scale2 = newZoom
                            } else {
                                pinchArea.scale2 = pinchArea.maximumScale
                            }
                        } else {
                            newZoom = pinchArea.scale1-0.1
                            if (newZoom >= pinchArea.minimumScale) {
                                pinchArea.scale2 = newZoom
                            } else {
                                pinchArea.scale2 = pinchArea.minimumScale
                            }
                        }
                        photoFrame.x = photoFrame.x + (pinchArea.x1-pinchArea.x2)*(1-pinchArea.scale1)
                        photoFrame.y = photoFrame.y + (pinchArea.y1-pinchArea.y2)*(1-pinchArea.scale1)
                    }                        
                }
            }
        }    
    }

I also changed the C++ class and removed Wheel event from there as we are overriding that in QML instead. One change that i did to C++ class is that drawing the image in the center now instead of (0,0).

//C++ file




CustomImage::CustomImage(QQuickItem* parent)
        : QQuickPaintedItem(parent)
        , m_zoom(1.0)
        , m_offset(QPointF(0, 0))
        , m_mousePos(0, 0)
        , m_scale(1.0)
    {
     
    }

QImage CustomImage::image() const
{
    return m_image;
}
void CustomImage::setImage(const QImage& image)
{
    m_image = image;    
    update();
}

void CustomImage::paint(QPainter* painter)
{   
    QRectF bounding_rect = boundingRect();
    QImage scaled = m_image.scaledToHeight(m_image.height());
    QPointF center = bounding_rect.center() - scaled.rect().center();

    center.setX(std::max(0., center.x()));
    center.setY(std::max(0., center.y()));

    painter->drawImage(center, scaled);
}
```

//Header file

```
class CustomImage: public QQuickPaintedItem
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QImage image READ image WRITE setImage NOTIFY imageChanged) 

  public:
    explicit CustomImage(QQuickItem* parent = nullptr);

    QImage image() const;

    Q_INVOKABLE void setImage(const QImage& image);

  signals:
    void imageChanged();

  protected:
    void paint(QPainter* painter) override;

  private:
    QImage m_image;
    qreal m_zoom;
    QPointF m_offset;
    QPointF m_mousePos;
    qreal m_scale;
};
```